# Java ImageIO.write() Runtime Exception

Tags: java

I was trying to follow the example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/examples/ForkBlur.java

```
/*
* Copyright (c) 2010, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
*
* Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
* modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
* are met:
*
*   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
*     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
*
*   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
*     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
*     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
*
*   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
*     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
*     from this software without specific prior written permission.
*
* THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
* IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
* THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
* PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
* CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
* EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
* PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
* PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
* LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
* NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
* SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*/

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 * ForkBlur implements a simple horizontal image blur. It averages pixels in the
 * source array and writes them to a destination array. The sThreshold value
 * determines whether the blurring will be performed directly or split into two
 * tasks.
 *
 * This is not the recommended way to blur images; it is only intended to
 * illustrate the use of the Fork/Join framework.
 */
public class ForkBlur extends RecursiveAction {

    private int[] mSource;
    private int mStart;
    private int mLength;
    private int[] mDestination;
    private int mBlurWidth = 15; // Processing window size, should be odd.

    public ForkBlur(int[] src, int start, int length, int[] dst) {
        mSource = src;
        mStart = start;
        mLength = length;
        mDestination = dst;
    }

    // Average pixels from source, write results into destination.
    protected void computeDirectly() {
        int sidePixels = (mBlurWidth - 1) / 2;
        for (int index = mStart; index < mStart + mLength; index++) {
            // Calculate average.
            float rt = 0, gt = 0, bt = 0;
            for (int mi = -sidePixels; mi <= sidePixels; mi++) {
                int mindex = Math.min(Math.max(mi + index, 0), mSource.length - 1);
                int pixel = mSource[mindex];
                rt += (float) ((pixel & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / mBlurWidth;
                gt += (float) ((pixel & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / mBlurWidth;
                bt += (float) ((pixel & 0x000000ff) >> 0) / mBlurWidth;
            }

            // Re-assemble destination pixel.
            int dpixel = (0xff000000)
                    | (((int) rt) << 16)
                    | (((int) gt) << 8)
                    | (((int) bt) << 0);
            mDestination[index] = dpixel;
        }
    }
    protected static int sThreshold = 10000;

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (mLength < sThreshold) {
            computeDirectly();
            return;
        }

        int split = mLength / 2;

        invokeAll(new ForkBlur(mSource, mStart, split, mDestination),
                new ForkBlur(mSource, mStart + split, mLength - split, 
                mDestination));
    }

    // Plumbing follows.
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String srcName = "awesome_face.jpg";
        File srcFile = new File(srcName);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(srcFile);

        System.out.println("Source image: " + srcName);

        BufferedImage blurredImage = blur(image);

        String dstName = "blurred-awesome-face.jpg";
        File dstFile = new File(dstName);
        ImageIO.write(blurredImage, "jpg", dstFile);

        System.out.println("Output image: " + dstName);

    }

    public static BufferedImage blur(BufferedImage srcImage) {
        int w = srcImage.getWidth();
        int h = srcImage.getHeight();

        int[] src = srcImage.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);
        int[] dst = new int[src.length];

        System.out.println("Array size is " + src.length);
        System.out.println("Threshold is " + sThreshold);

        int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(processors) + " processor"
                + (processors != 1 ? "s are " : " is ")
                + "available");

        ForkBlur fb = new ForkBlur(src, 0, src.length, dst);

        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        pool.invoke(fb);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Image blur took " + (endTime - startTime) + 
                " milliseconds.");

        BufferedImage dstImage =
                new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        dstImage.setRGB(0, 0, w, h, dst, 0, w);

        return dstImage;
    }
}
```

I copied this code to my computer and compiled and ran it and received the following error:

```
Source image: awesome_face.jpg
Array size is 100000
Threshold is 10000
4 processors are available
Image blur took 19 milliseconds.
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid argument to native writeImage
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeImage(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeOnThread(JPEGImageWriter.java:1058)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.write(JPEGImageWriter.java:360)
    at javax.imageio.ImageWriter.write(ImageWriter.java:615)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.doWrite(ImageIO.java:1612)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1536)
    at ForkBlur.main(ForkBlur.java:112)
```

It looks like the problem is at line 112 in the ImageIO.write() method. I looked at the API for this method here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html From my understanding the arguments to write() are okay but something is really messed up at runtime.

Does anyone know what is wrong with this program?

Regards,

...

Comment: It works for me on java 1.8.0. What java version are you compiling and running with?

Comment: I am using 1.7 more specifically: `java version "1.7.0_79"`